# Can the Lumia 920 sync with Windows 7 over Bluetooth?

Tags: 8.0, nokia-lumia-920, bluetooth

I've had my Lumia 920 connected via USB to sync just fine, but I'd much rather connect it via Bluetooth. So far though, I haven't found an option in the software.

Is this even possible? If so, what's the process?

Answer (score 2):

Lumia 920 runs Windows Phone 8, which currently does not support any wireless syncing.

The closest thing you can get is syncing photos/images to OneDrive.
Hopefully this is a feature that will come, together with syncing via WiFi.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to [transfer](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/basics/share-files-over-bluetooth) individual files to and from your phone, but a [sync](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/file-sharing-manual-syncing-bluetooth-tips-for-windows-phone-8/) is not supported.